# Apple Script on iPhone

Tags: objective-c, applescript

I have one Apple script and its working fine on Mac. I want to use it into iPhone application. How can I integrate to iPhone application?

Answer (score 3):

Also AppleScript uses Carbon and Carbon AppleEvents, so trying to get this on a iPhone is pretty much impossible you would pretty much have to write your own AppleScript interpreter, I also would not see much point in having AppleScripts on an iPhone since the main purpose of AppleScript is to control other applications by sending the AppleEvents. Have you thought about using JavaScripts I was looking at that for a web scraping application, using Javascript meant I could update the web scraping code quickly without having to resubmit my app to Apple.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback. Actually, I have Apple Script for my MAC application and I just want to convert it into iPhone application. But, I have no idea how to integrate it to iPhone Objective C project. So, can you please provide me any specific steps for integrating it to iPhone project?

Comment: Are you saying this is a AppleScript Cocoa application because if that is the case you are out of luck, you are just going to have to rewrite it in objective-C, sorry. AppleScripts goes way back pre Mac OS X (System 7 I think) and was carried over to Mac OS X with carbon, and carbon just doesn't exist on iOS, it not just the lack of an AppleScript interpreter, but AppleScripts is based around AppleEvents which is also a pre Mac OS X feature carried over with Carbon.

Comment: Okies. Thanks for your comments. So, I cant use that Apple script developed for MAC application to iOS application. right? Is there any way for it? or I have to develop rewrite code in Objective C is the only solution?

Comment: Yes, there are some other development environments that let you write projects that will be compiled into iPhone and Android apps, but that still means writing you code from scratch, I have heard of people who wanted to convert program written in no longer supposed languages on mac os X into Cocoa/Objective-c writing there own source code translator, but the sound like more work that it is worth, you could try do a google search for a source code translator from AppleScript to Objective-C but I don't like your chances.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, you can't easily do that. This excerpt is from the latest [iOS Developer Program License Agreement](https://developer.apple.com/membercenter/index.action#updateAgreement):

> 3.3.2  ... Interpreted code may only be used in an Application if all scripts, code and interpreters are packaged in the Application and not downloaded. The only exception to the foregoing is scripts and code downloaded and run by Apple's built-in WebKit framework, provided that such scripts and code do not change the primary purpose of the Application by providing features or functionality that are inconsistent with the intended and advertised purpose of the Application as submitted to the App Store.

So, in theory it is allowed, nut since AppleScript is not supported by iOS SDK, you should also package an AppleScript interpreter with your app.

Comment: But,If I have interpreted with application,then is there any way or steps to integrate it? Can anyone provide me steps or any sample code for it?

Comment: I actually don't think you can get an applescript interpreter for iOS... there is no source code for it, so you should write one on your own... it would be much more easier to implement in ObjC the functionality you currently have in AppleScript...

Comment: Thanks for your feedback. I have source code for the MAC application in Apple script and its working fine. So, I just want to perform same activity on iPhone application. But, I have no idea regarding it. I have never used Apple Script in my application.